# React - Change icon when click on a list element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, icons

I have this class where the state of a dropdown is false

```
class StartRetroForm extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
      dropdown: false
    }
  }
```

Then I have this function that what is does is to display a list of projects in a dropdown

```
  renderDropdown () {
    if (this.state.dropdown) {
      const projectsList = this.props.projects.map((project) => (
        <li className='u-cursor--pointer c-start-retro-line'
          key={project.get('id')}
          onClick={() => this.handleProjectSelection(project.get('id'))} >
          <i className='fa fa-square' style={{color: project.get('color')}}></i>
          {project.get('name')}
        </li>
      ))
      return (
        <div>
          <ul className='c-start-retro-folder-dropdown'
            name='projectList'
            form='start-retro-form'>
            {projectsList}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

As is shown in the next image:
[image]

Then in the render() method I have the folder icon that every time is clicked it opens and closes.

```
    <i
      onClick={() => this.setState({ dropdown: !this.state.dropdown })}
      className='u-cursor--pointer fa fa-folder-open'>
    </i>
    {this.renderDropdown()}
```

But What I'm trying to do, is that every time a project is selected, the folder icon will disappear and it will show the first two letters of the name of the project, something like this: `project.get('name').substring(0, 2)`

Like its shown in the next image:

[image]

How can I make the folder disappear and shows the two first letters of a project when it's selected?

Answer (score 2):

```
{this.state.selectedProject && this.state.selectedProject.name.substring(2,0)}
    {!this.state.selectedProject &&
        <span>
            <i
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                className={this.state.dropdown === false ? 'u-cursor--pointer fa fa-folder' : 'u-cursor--pointer fa fa-folder-open'}>
            </i>
            {this.renderDropdown()}
        </span>
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hggbLbf9/

You can basically have a state variable which checks for selection and if selection is present you can show the selected project and hide the folder icon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refactor how you are showing the folder icon in the first place. I would personally move what I did below into a function depending on how complex it's going to get.

This basically says if hasSelectedProject === true (whatever hasSelectedProject looks like) show the folder icon, otherwise show the project code. The logic is basic also, so again I would move it to a function, but the basic idea is you needed to pull out the folder icon, it was too tightly coupled.

```
return (
        <div>
          <ul name='projectList'
            form='start-retro-form'>
                {!this.state.hasSelectedProject ?
                  <span className='c-start-retro-folder-dropdown'></span>
                :
                  <span>Project name code here</span>
                }
                {projectsList}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
```

Comment: But I want the folder icon to be the default and every time I click one of the elements of the list, the folder will change. The folder icon is the last code snipped I send `    <i
      onClick={() => this.setState({ dropdown: !this.state.dropdown })}
      className='u-cursor--pointer fa fa-folder-open'>
    </i>` that's the folder

Comment: so you want the folder to disappear once a project is selected?

Comment: yes! :) I want the folder disappear and be replaced by two letters, once a project is selected